# Docker pulling unauthorized - Docker and Github actions

Tags: github, docker-compose, github-actions, digital-ocean

my deploy script is as follows:

```
  - name: Log in to GitHub Packages
    run: echo ${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN} | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ secrets.NAMESPACE }} --password-stdin
    env:
      PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

  - name: Build and deploy images on DigitalOcean
    env:
      SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
    run: |
      scp  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r ./.env ./docker-compose_prod.yml root@${{ secrets.DIGITAL_OCEAN_IP_ADDRESS }}:/app
      ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${{ secrets.DIGITAL_OCEAN_IP_ADDRESS }} << 'ENDSSH'
        cd /app
        source .env
        docker login ghcr.io -u $NAMESPACE -p $PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
        docker pull $WEB_IMAGE
        docker pull $NGINX_IMAGE
        docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
      ENDSSH
```

and the error that I get is

> Pulling web
> (ghcr.io/***/testdriver_tutorial/web:ba673356fe8a9abcf25700b8a12619e414bbaf7c)... Head
> https://ghcr.io/v2/***/testdriver_tutorial/web/manifests/ba673356fe8a9abcf25700b8a12619e414bbaf7c:
> unauthorized

The Log in to `GitHub Packages` step shows it has been successful

[image]

**UPDATE**

I just did `docker login ghcr.io -u $NAMESPACE -p $PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN` on the digital ocean droplet and it requests a password.

How can I switch off this password authentication so it only uses `PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with docker pull, the problem was with the command executed before docker login which was `source .env`

```
        run: |
          scp  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r ./.env ./docker-compose.prod.yml root@${{ secrets.DIGITAL_OCEAN_IP_ADDRESS }}:/app
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${{ secrets.DIGITAL_OCEAN_IP_ADDRESS }} << 'ENDSSH'
            cd /app
            source .env
            docker login ghcr.io -u $NAMESPACE -p $PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

There was a special character in the `source .env` - specifically in the Django Secret Key. The GitHub actions continued to the next step. I am not sure how `unauthorized error` resulted, but fixing the syntax in source .env made it log in.